# How to run a command recursively on all files except for those under .svn directories

Tags: bash, unix, shell, find

Here is how i run dos2unix recursively on all files:

```
find -exec dos2unix {} \;
```

What do i need to change to make it skip over files under .svn/ directories?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Actual tested solution:

```
$ find . -type f \! -path \*/\.svn/\* -exec dos2unix {} \;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a general script on which you can change the last line as required.
I've taken the technique from my [findrepo](http://www.pixelbeat.org/scripts/findrepo) script:

```
repodirs=".git .svn CVS .hg .bzr _darcs"
for dir in $repodirs; do
    repo_ign="$repo_ign${repo_ign+" -o "}-name $dir"
done

find \( -type d -a \( $repo_ign \)  \) -prune -o \
     \( -type f -print0 \) |
xargs -r0 \
dos2unix
```

Answer (score 1):

Just offering an additional tip: piping the result through xargs instead of using find's -exec option will increase the performance when going through a large directory structure if the filtering program accepts multiple arguments, as this will reduce the number of fork()'s, so:

find <opts> | xargs dos2unix

One caveat: piping through xargs will fail horribly if any filenames include whitespace.

Comment: `find ... -print0 | xargs -0 ...` handles filenames with spaces.

Answer (score -1):

In bash

```
for fic in **/*; dos2unix $fic
```

Or even better in zsh

```
for fic in **/*(.); dos2unix $fic
```

Comment: How does this skip `.svn/` directories?

Comment: if dotglob is off, it will skip hidden files. But other hidden files will also be skipped, which i think is not what OP wants.

Comment: Oooops, sorry!

for root in {*,.*}(N); do 
  [[ $root = .svn ]] && continue ;
  for fic in $root/**/*(.); do dos2unix $fic ;
done
;

works but the find version is better now...

Comment: +1.  Thanks. Works for me. I do not have to bother about svn files. 
`for plfile in *.pl; do dos2unix $plfile; done;
for plfile in **/*.pl; do dos2unix $plfile; done;`

Answer (score -1):

```
find . -path ./.svn -prune -o -print0   | xargs -0 -i echo dos2unix "{}" "{}"
```

if you have bash 4.0

```
shopt -s globstar
shopt -s dotglob
for file in /path/**
do
  case "$file" in
    */.svn* )continue;;
  esac
  echo dos2unix $file $file
done
```

Comment: Changing -path ./.svn to -path '*/.svn' should fix it.

Comment: `-i` is deprecated, use `-I{}` instead. Also, why two `"{}"`?